# Always assign vs check equality and assign

Tags: c++, performance

Is there any noticeable performance difference between:

`if (a != b) a = b;` 
and
`a = b;`

when `a` and `b` are both of the same built-in type like `int` or `bool` or maybe a really simple and small `struct`?

As I understand second expression will write to memory every time (which I assume is a heavier operation than read), while first one will do it only if `a` and `b` are not already equal.

Or probably it depends on how often is `b` value changed?

I understand that it's more of "++i vs i++" kind of a question, I am curious though

Comment: You could have answered this yourself by doing some simple benchmarks...

Comment: it depends on your code.

Comment: If you're concerned about performance at this level, then the context will matter much more, such as: how often is this line of code encountered, and roughly how often is it likely that `a == b` versus not? Clearly, if `a != b` frequently, then it's more expensive than just `a = b` without the `if`. That said, if you're having code performance issues, I'd be really surprised if this line of code is having much impact.

Comment: @Borgleader But probably there are some interesting points regarding branch predictions or cache, which I would like to know if it's the case

Comment: That's where running your own benchmarks come into play using your code. Nobody's going to be able to just look at this line of code, especially out of context, and give you a definitive answer to your question.

Comment: @Borgleader: and that might lead you to think that it behaves the same way in a complex scenario. Which isn't necessarily the case.

Comment: One thing that nobody has mentioned is that the straight out assignment will unconditionally dirty the cacheline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends.

For x86 CPUs, cost of operations involved in your program, will be roughly as follows:

- non-cached read (i.e. read from RAM which is not cached yet): ~100 clocks
- cached read: 3 to ~10 clocks
- register read: 1/2 clock (value is very rough, as there is no such single operation "read")
- write: varies and depends, but often ~1 clock
- comparison: up to 5-10 clocks if compiler guess "which branch will happen" is wrong (this is known as "pipeline stall"); otherwise - 1 clock.

Using this information, you might be able to make some guesstimates ;-).

For other (non-x86) desktop/server/mobile CPUs numbers will be different, but overall picture will be more or less the same.

Comment: Is write really faster than a non-register read? As I understand there could be a write cache-miss too? Or if both are cached, is it really true that cached read is 3 to 10 and cached write is 1?

Comment: @mambo_sun: write timing is one thing which is not 100% clear to me. What I know is that it MAY be implemented as 1 clock (you don't need to block execution pipeline while you're writing data, you just need to place it to "write buffer" and can continue further), but on the other hand excessive write cache-misses may indeed cause overload of the memory bus, which will cause delays for other operations down the road. So while singular write MAY be 1 clock even in the case of cache miss, it MAY have difficult-to-quantify implications a bit down the road.

Comment: @mambo_sun Unlike reads, writes don't block since there isn't anything depending on them (unless you immediately load from the same address). But that doesn't mean that they are free. Even for processors with out-of-order execution, they have a limit to how much re-ordering can be done. If a write cache miss blocks for too long, it will still stall the execution pipeline.

Comment: I think you should add a reference from where you took those numbers.

Comment: @bolov: while the numbers are more or less well-known, I don't know of one single source for them. If anybody knows it - feel free to edit the answer.